# jQuery delay() works after effect, but not before?

Tags: jquery, delay

I'm showing a line of text using a typewriter effect [http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jTypeWriter].

I want to: 
1) Delay 3 seconds 
2) Show typewriter text 
3) Delay 4 seconds 
4) Fade out

But step 1 doesn't happen with this code:
`$('blockquote').delay(3000).jTypeWriter({duration:1}).delay(4000).fadeOut();`

Why does `delay()` not work at the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delay() only works within an animation queue - so yes, an animation needs to be called before it will work as you expect.

setTimeout() is probably the way to go:

```
var t = window.setTimeout(function(){
    $('#myDiv').jTypeWriter({duration:1}).delay(4000).fadeOut();
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Your second example would work, but not the first. Adding an `.animate()` to the beginning of the queue doesn't change the fact that `.jTypeWriter()` isn't part of the animation queue. It will execute immediately.

Answer (score 1):

To use `.delay()`, you would need to add the `jTypeWriter()` to the animation queue. You can use  jQuery's `.queue()` method for this:

```
$('blockquote').delay(3000)
               .queue(function( n ){ $(this).jTypeWriter({duration:1}); n(); })
               .delay(4000)
               .fadeOut();
```

Calling the `n()` parameter in the `.queue()` is used to allow the next element in the queue to continue.

- http://api.jquery.com/queue/

Answer (score 0):

```
timeOut = setTimeout(function(){
        $('blockquote').jTypeWriter({duration:1}).delay(4000).fadeOut();
    },3000)
```

It should be working but it is untested code.